# html input pattern attribute not working correctly

Tags: html, regex, validation, input, browser

I writed input that should accept only actual digits for example:
1.2 - accepted
1.1.2 - not accepted
+123.53e-10.1 - accepted
etc.

here is full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Digit" pattern="\s*[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?)?\s*">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My code is working only in Internet Explorer. What do I need to do to make the code work properly in Chrome, FireFox, Opera etc.

Comment: I didn't understand which numbers exactly you want or what is the general concept of your UI. In any case, you should 1) <button type="submit> it's not an input.
2) Don't forget in self-closing tags, to ass "/". <input  type="text"... />

Comment: I mean that kind of numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the signs **+** and **-** that are inside the square brackets:

```
\s*[\-\+]?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][\-\+]?\d+(\.\d+)?)?\s*
``
```

Comment: Great! I'm happy to hear that it's working correctly for you! And have a look to the already answered question, @WiktorStribiżew explained it in details.